# creating product with installer script in magento custom module

Tags: magento

i am trying to create a product (with basic attributes) when the custom module get installed.
i am developing a magento custom module which requires a product to be created at the time of its installation. i have successfully created a product in programmatic way (on fly) but it requires to be created only when the specific parameter received and also after successful transaction it needs to be deleted so i was asked ,in order to save the hassle why not create the product when the module get installed via installer script (in setup directory). 
but i am not able to find the way yet as i am new to the magento module development. 
any suggestions , is it a right approach? if so what should be the process? is there a specific even that can be triggered when the module get installed?

thanking you all in anticipation

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way:

```
    $data = array(
        'name'                => '<name>',
        'sku'                 => '<sku>',
        'attribute_set_id'    => <attribute_set_id>,
        'type_id'             => <product_type_code>,
        'website_ids'         => array(1),
        'description'         => '<description>',
        'short_description'   => '<short_description>',
        'price'               => <price>,
        'tax_class_id'        => <tax_class_id>,
        'visibility'          => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH,
        'status'              => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED,
        'category_ids'        => array(<category_ids>),
    );

    $productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productModel->setData($data)
        ->save();
```

Comment: thank you for quick response, i will try this and inform accordingly.